# if-then statement in bash to toggle screen resolution

Tags: linux, display, shell-script, bash-scripting, xrandr

How do I phrase a script that checks screen resolution with xrandr and changes resolution depending on what it is currently? Which is to say, toggles the resolution.

Sample output of `xrandr -q`

```
   1920x1080     59.98 +  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99*   59.94    59.95    59.82
```

How does it need to be phrased to check if the current resolution is 1600x900, then run `xrandr -s 0`, but if the current resolution is 1920x1080 run `xrandr -s 4`?

In short the question is how to make the script recognize the output of xrandr -q in order to toggle resolutions. For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if <current resolution is 1920x1080>
then
  xrandr -s 5
elif <current resolution is 1600x900>
then
  xrandr -s 0
else
 <do nothing>
fi
```

Basically I need a means for the script to recognize which line the asterisk is on and switch it to the other one. How would that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708029/toggle-screen-resolution-with-a-script-how) by @[chobara](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13792/choroba) on unix.stackexchange.com

> Use process substitution:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> read resolution _rest < <(xrandr | grep '\*')
>
> if [[ $resolution = 1920x1080 ]] ; then
>     xrandr -s 5
> elif [[ $resolution = 1600x900 ]] ; then
>     xrandr -s 0
> else
>     echo Unknown resolution >&2
> fi
> ```

Answer (score 2):

### Example of solution

The solution can be customized according to your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYRES=$(xrandr -q | grep "\*" | awk '{ print $1; }')
echo -e "\nResolution is $MYRES\n"
case "$MYRES" in
  "1920x1080")
    echo "Size = 5"
    xrandr -s 5
    ;;
  "1680x1050")
    echo "Size = 4"
    xrandr -s 4
    ;;
  "1600x1024")
    echo "Size = 4"
    xrandr -s 4
    ;;
  "1400x1050")
    echo "Size = 3"
    xrandr -s 3
    ;;
  "1600x900")
    echo "Size = 0"
    xrandr -s 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Do nothing."
    ;;
esac
```